# Spring security default login form disappears when adding WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a `Spring Boot 2` application with some controllers.
I wat to add `Spring Security` **and allow some urls for only authenticated users, whereas others should be accessible for all.**
But when I use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure cecurity per-url, **auto-generated pages for "/login" and "/error" disappear**.

If I try to add the simplest possible configuration, it works and protects all urls:

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: "admin"
      password: "1234"
      roles: "ADMIN"
```

`pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And every action redirects me to `/login` page with login form, until I log in with credentials I configured.

However, If I add a configuration class to customize the behavior, the default login form seems to be missing, and I keep getting `/error` page instead because there is no such resource as `/login`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("1234").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
    }
}
```

Here are some debug logs (the rest is omitted for readability):

```
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e4de2840: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
...
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e4de2840: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2a3c0a9c, returned: 1
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/login", parameters={}
DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@27581ee6
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
...
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

At the end I get error page in browser, saying that there is no `/error` page either.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 21 14:53:17 CET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Not Found
```

For some reason, auto-generated pages for "/login" and "/error" disappear when I use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration class. Where are they gone?

Moreover, this `Previously Authenticated:` looks suspicious to me, because It was a fresh app start. But if I try to disable anonymous users with `http.anonymous().disable()`, I start getting 403 error for any url. Can it be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing: `.formLogin().loginPage("/login")`

Something like:

```
 http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/private").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/error").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
```

Above would require a custom designed login page.
**If you want to use Spring security's default login page then just add below**

```
.and().formLogin()
```

That's all